# Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA) License cost

Tags: sitecore-sxa

We have been asked by our client to consider SXA for a new project. I have not used SXA. I only have some theoretical knowledge. I have few questions:

1. What additional license cost will be incurred by the client towards SXA. I learnt from a forum that if a company has partner license with Sitecore, Developers can use SXA as the license file has SXA attribute in it. Else, the client will have to pay an extra amount for SXA.
2. Is it possible to arrive at a license cost range? As the project is gonna be executed by us (vendor), assume 3 developers will be working on a project and at least one person would need to use SXA.
3. If you have implemented projects using SXA, please help us understand how much of effort saving we are looking at. I know it depends on various factors. But if it's a simple project let's say 10 Week (one person effort) project, how much effort we may be able to save. Like 1 wk, 2 wk etc.

Comment: I'm guessing Sitecore licencing is on a case-by-case basis.  You'll most likely need to approach Sitecore and ask them for a quote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about **programming** - but a licensing question